# R time series or data outliers

Tags: r, time-series, outliers, multivariate-time-series

have data that has several aberrant values ​​and I want to correct this to make forecasts knowing that my values ​​are normally between and 4. as I have to take these values ​​without touching the normal values ​​(between 1 and 4). Thank you

| Trafic | date |
| --- | --- |
| 107 | 01/02/2020 |
| 60 | 01/03/2020 |
| 3.4 | 01/04/2020 |
| 3.2 | 01/05/2020 |
| 2.9 | 01/06/2020 |

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. I don't follow exactly what you want. If `Trafic` is normally between 1 and 4, then the first two observations are probably not right, is that correct? And if that is the case, what do you want to do with them? Show us your ideal output after the code you want runs.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Hi, So as I said I want to do forecasting so I can't do scale(). What I must have at the end are values ​​that are close to the majority, that is to say between 2.8 and 3.5 because the first values ​​are exceptional values. ( 2.8, 2.98, 3.5, 3.1, 2.9, 3.2 ... here is an example output . Merci

Answer (score 0):

You can try scaling the variable using scale() function.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).